# Error when can't run swf when add event click using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<a title="click" href="test.swf" class="game-in-link" style="background:#000;width:100%;height:450px;display:block;">CLICK ON PLAY</a>
<div>
<!--
<object width="100%" height="450">
   <param name="movie" value="test.swf"></param>
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="450"></embed>
</object>
-->
</div>
```

And jquery:

```
// Get SWF file
jQuery("a.game-in-link").one('click', function () {
    var anchor = jQuery(this);
    anchor.html(anchor.html().replace('<div><!--', '').replace('--></div>', ''));
    anchor.removeAttr('href');
    return false;
});
```

=> Error can't filw test.swf, How to get SWF file with result is ?

```
<object width="100%" height="450">
   <param name="movie" value="test.swf"></param>
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="450"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
jQuery("a.game-in-link").one('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = jQuery(this).next(); //get next div
    var a = anchor.html().replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '');
    anchor.html(a).prev().attr('href', '#'); //substitute html and a href
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
<a title="click" href="test.swf" class="game-in-link" style="background:#000;width:100%;height:450px;display:block;">CLICK ON PLAY</a>
<div id="swfPlayer" style="display:none;">
<object width="100%" height="450">
   <param name="movie" value=""></param>
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
   <embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="450"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

And Jquery

```
// Get SWF file
jQuery("a.game-in-link").one('click', function () {
    var anchor = jQuery(this);
    var swfPlayer= jQuery('#swfPlayer');
    swfPlayer.find('param[name=movie]').prop("value", anchor.prop("href"));
    swfPlayer.find('embed').prop("src", anchor.prop("href"));
    anchor.removeAttr('href');
    swfPlayer.show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 only modification I would make would be to wrap the whole thing in a containing element and make the jQuery selectors relative to the link clicked and it's containing parent rather than using absolute IDs to find the Flash embed.